# Should a question be flagged for having no research at all?

Tags: discussion

For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25728688, the OP didn't research by any possible means. Is there a flag for this case? Or does this question just deserve a downvote if I think it's of  low quality? (I guessed this by the number of the downvotes)

Comment: How would you expect the moderators to respond to a "no research" flag?

Comment: Downvote/comment if you wish. Could flag to be closed as "too broad". But I don't see any reason for a custom flag

Comment: @Yannis I don't get what you mean.

Comment: @KugBuBu When you flag a post you're saying that you feel some action should be taken, but you don't have the ability to perform that action yourself.  For example, you might feel a post should be deleted, or closed, or migrated, but if you can't do those things, you'd flag for a moderator to do them.  If you're going to flag a post, you should generally have some idea of what you expect the moderator to do.  If you can't think of what they could possibly do to resolve the situation, then why are you bringing it to their attention?

Comment: Downvote, close vote if it's too broad, but **don't** flag. These kind of ill-researched posts should be handled by community. Flags are for situations which the community can't handle.

Comment: @codeMagic I think my reason is that it's similar to fix my code question by the mean that the user not particularly chose to debug\research and do the whole effort for it? It's a bit hard for me to explain I think.

Comment: @Servy I think that closing the question won't help or is the most effective. Didn't thought of it.

Comment: With the extensive ability of the *community* to moderate the site, about the only thing you need to use a moderator flag for anymore is "delete this immediately".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not having done research is a reason to downvote, but it is not, by itself, a reason to flag, or to take any other moderation action.  Posts that are very poorly researched often do have other problems with them though.  By all means take the time to look at the post and see if it has any of those other problems, such as being unclear, too broad, etc.  If you notice other problems that *do* have a corresponding flag, then flag for *those* reasons.

Answer (score 10):

Moderator flags are for situations that cannot be handled by the community.

The proper response for a poorly researched question is a downvote.